# VBA 2 Pivot Tables different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched the web, but I'm having trouble finding a solution to my issue. I have a workbook with 2 tabs of data. I am using VBA to create 2 pivot tables on 2 different sheets. The code runs through the first pivot table perfectly. The Second set of code for the second pivot table stops at the pivot Cache. Any ideas?

```
 Dim sht As Worksheet
 Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
 Dim pvt As PivotTable
 Dim StartPvt As String
 Dim SrcData As String

 Dim finRow As String
  With ActiveWorkbook
  finRow = Sheets("WorbookName").Range("A200000").End(xlUp).Row
   SrcData = Sheets("WorkbookName").Name & "!" & Range("A1:I" & finRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
  `End With`

  'Create a new worksheet
  Set sht = Sheets.Add

  'Pivot starting point?
   StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" & sht.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

  'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data`
  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
   SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

  'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
   Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
   TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
   TableName:="PivotTable1")


   Set pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")`

 ================ Second Pivot table code  

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String`

'Pivot table range
Dim finRow As String
With Sheets("Data")
finRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A200000").End(xlUp).Row
  SrcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("A3:CB" & finRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)`
 End With

 'Create a new worksheet

  Set sht = Sheets.Add

 'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
   StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" & sht.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

   'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data`
   Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
  Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
    TableName:="PivotTable2")
```

Any help provided is much appreciated. Thank you, Matt

Comment: The code just stops?  No error message?

Comment: Run-time error '1004':   The Pivot table field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable report you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns. if you are changing the name of a pivot table field, you must type a new name for the field.     Thanks for the question.

Comment: `finRow` should be `Long`, not `String`

Answer (score 0):

At this point in your code, `ActiveSheet` is where you placed the previous pivot table, not on the sheet where you are intending to pull data.  In both cases you use a `With` statement, but do not use.

```
Dim finRow As String
With Sheets("Data")
finRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A200000").End(xlUp).Row
  SrcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("A3:CB" & finRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)`
 End With
```

Try modifying...

```
Dim finRow As Long
With Sheets("Data")
  finRow = .Range("A200000").End(xlUp).Row
  SrcData = .Range("A3:CB" & finRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)`
End With
```

Comment: Still no luck. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I have found this site to be a helpful reminder of how to create pivot tables...https://excelchamps.com/blog/vba-to-create-pivot-table/

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out.